# Where does firebase save it's simple login users?

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, rest-firebase

I am currently using `firebase` to make an `ionic app`. I am using `firebase simple login` for `social auth` (`facebook, twitter, email & password`). The auth works perfectly, it `$broadcasts` the `authed user`. However it doesn't seem to create a user in the actual `firebase db`. I was wondering how I can get the users that have been `authed` using my `app`.

Answer (score 15):

For most of the authentication protocols it supports, Firebase doesn't store user data anywhere. Even for the protocols where it *does* store data (I only know of email+password doing this), it stores this information in a place that your application can't access (though you can find those users in the dashboard of your Firebase).

To quote the [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing):

> It does not store profile or user state in your Firebase. To persist user data you must save it to your Firebase.

What most applications end up doing, is keeping a list of users inside their Firebase that they manage themselves. So when a user first authenticates with the application, it creates a node under `/users/<uid>` that contains the information for that user.

See this section of the [Firebase documentation that describes storing user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing).

Answer (score 7):

Firebase does not store profile or user state in your Firebase instance. To persist user data you must save it to your Firebase.

Firebase provides multiple [authentications services](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html)

1. Using existing social login providers such Facebook, Twitter, Google, and GitHub. Using these services provides an option for your users to access your application without creating a new account.
2. Using built-in support for logging in with email & password. This requires registration and account creation that is handled by Firebase. The user account information is stored outside you application.
3. Using a custom authentication to implement existing server-side authentication, single sign-on, legacy systems, or third-party OAuth based services (such as Yahoo).

Once authenticated, Firebase return a variable `auth` to your application that you can use for [authorization and access control](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html).  This variable is null for unauthenticated users, but for authenticated users it is an object containing the user's unique (`auth.uid`) and potentially other data about the user.

> If you want to persist additional user information such as name
>   and location, then you need to use `auth.uid` and store it in your
>   Firebase with additional profile data.

Internally, Firebase generates JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) and creates authenticated sessions by calling Firebase.loginWithCustomToken() with those tokens. Each user is assigned a uid (a unique ID), which is guaranteed to be distinct across all providers, and to never change for a specific authenticated user.

Answer (score 6):

The **`user data for firebase authentication`** is stored in **`firebaseLocalStorageDb`** in **`IndexedDB`**. After login to website, if you delete  **`firebaseLocalStorageDb`**, the **`login user data for firebase authentication`** is all deleted so you need to log in website again.

[image]