# Firebase retrieving user.email with user id

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im currently using Firebase to manage my user. I like the idea that i can store my user infos such as email, photoUrl and others into

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

user?.updateEmail("user@example.com") { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // Email upenter code heredated.
  }
}
```

now of course this only work for the current sign in user, if i want to retrieve the same info of another user by using another user id how can I retrieve this.

Comment: There is no built-in API to look up a user's information by their UID. Most developers keep a list of user information in another data source (such as the Firebase Database) for that reason. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735377/where-does-firebase-save-its-simple-login-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a "users" child in your Database's JSON tree and separate each user by their user ID that you can get with `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser.uid`.

So your JSON tree would look something like this:

```
"root"
    "users"
        "userID12345"
            "email"
            "photoURL"
```

Then you can pull that data from Firebase in your app by calling:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
//store the snapshot.value in a dictionary and read your data from there
})
```